# PySerial: Open port takes too long

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm communicating from my PC to a Nucleo-Board via UART. For that I'm using [PySerial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), a FTDI-USB-Cable for data connection and a USB-Cable for power. `open()` works fine, except when I remove the power from my Nucleo-Board. Then `open()` needs way too long (2-4 seconds). "Okay, then just don't remove the power from the Nucleo-Board". Yeah true, but I want to handle this case -> it will open an error window. The only problem is, that it takes 2-4 seconds to open that window because `open()` takes too long.

A problem could be that the UART cable is still connected which makes the COM-Port available which won't raise an error when using `open()`. But I don't know why it takes so long. It doesn't communicate with the Board yet, it just opens the COM Port, right? If it already communicates, then it could be a problem, because the Board does not respond because it's not connected to the power.

My code to check how long `open()` takes:

```py
start_serialwrite1 = time.perf_counter()

try:
    self.ser.open()

    end_serialwrite1 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"time serialwrite1: {end_serialwrite1-start_serialwrite1}")
except serial.SerialException as e:
    print("ERROR")
    self.ser.close()
```

Output, when I unplug the power cable:

```
time serialwrite1: 3.3720932
```

Comment: It seems that the port name is not specified, but did you forget the description when asking? [Opening serial ports](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html)

Comment: @kunif the port is specified (but not in the question)

Comment: It may not have enough information for others to reproduce and investigate the problem. Please refer to these help articles to improve the question content and source code. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Or you may want to go to these sites. [Electorical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)